# Solution to one-dimensional Wave Equation with Method of Characteristics

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Consider the

> **Problem.** Let $\gamma$ be a parameterized curve in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ by $\gamma: I \to \Omega$, where $I$ is an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\Omega$ an open in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Let $a,b,c: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be given functions. Determine a function $\varphi(x,y)$ solution of the equation
>   $$a(x,y)\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x} + b(x,y)\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y} = c(x,y) \tag{Eq 1}$$
>   where $\varphi(\gamma(t)) = \varphi_{0}(t)$ with $\varphi_{0}: I \to \mathbb{R}$ is a given function.

*Proof.* (just a loosely idea) Fixed a point $\gamma_{0} = \gamma_{0}(s_{0}) = \gamma_{0}(x_{0},y_{0})$ of $\gamma$, consider the curve $\Gamma(t) = (x(t),y(t))$ passing through $\gamma_{0}$, that is, $\Gamma(0) = \gamma_{0}$. Define $z(t) = \varphi(x(t),y(t))$ where $\varphi$ is a solution of Eq 1. If $\Gamma$ is differentiable, by the Chain Rule,
$$\frac{dz}{dt} = \langle \Gamma'(t), \nabla\varphi(\Gamma(t)) \rangle = \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d\varphi}{dx} + \frac{dy}{dt}\frac{d\varphi}{dy}.$$
Therefore, if $\Gamma$ satisfies the system of ODE
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt} = a(x,y),&x(0) = x_{0}\\
\frac{dy}{dt} = b(x,y),&y(0) = y_{0},
\end{cases}\tag{Sy 1}$$
we can the solution $\varphi$ solving
$$\frac{dz}{dt} = c(x,y),\quad z(0)=\varphi(s_{0}).$$
If we repeat the previous argument for all points $\gamma(s)$, $s \in I$, we obtain a family of curves on which the solution $\varphi$ can be determined.

The solutions of the Sy 1 define a change of variables, that is, a function
$$f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$$
$$(t,s) \mapsto (x,y)$$
and the Inverse Function Theorem ensures a solution if $(a,b)$ is transversal to curve $\gamma$ where $(a,b)$ represents $(x,y) \mapsto (a(x,y),b(x,y))$.

---

---

My objective is to apply the Method of Characteristics (the **Problem**) to solve the one-dimensional linear **Wave Equation** that is given by

> $$\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial^{2} x} - c_{0}^{2}\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial^{2} y} = 0$$

and we write
$$\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial^{2} x} - c_{0}^{2}\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial^{2} y} = \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + c_{0}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} - c_{0}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)u = 0.$$
Let
$$\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} - c_{0}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)u = v(x,y) = v.$$
Then it's enough to solve

> $$\underbrace{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - c_{0}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = v}_{(1)}\quad\text{and}\quad\underbrace{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + c_{0}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0}_{(2)}$$

I broke the Wave Equation in (1) and (2) because the **Problem** is only for order $1$, since the partial  derivatives are of order $1$. Then I think that solving the two equations, I'll find a solution for Wave Equation. This is the way that I found to use the **Problem**.

Now, I want to use the **Problem** for solve (2) and so, use the solution for (2) to solve (1).

I couldn't apply the above problem to get a solution to the equations (1) and (2). Hans Lundmark gave me a good reference, but in it, the author does the construction with some different details and my professor wants me to use the problem, exactly as it is, to get the solution. I wish someone could help me with this.

Comment: PDE by Pinchover Rubinstein? If that doesn't help, then perhaps I don't understand your question.

Comment: I wrote the problem wrong. Corrected due to Hans observation. I'll read what you suggested! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in the equation that you wrote :

$$\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial^{2} x} + c\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial^{2} y} = \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + c\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} - c\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)u = 0.$$
The correct equation is :
$$\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial^{2} x} - c^2\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial^{2} y} = \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + c\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} - c\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)u = 0.$$
And moreover it is true only if $c=$constant.

If $c=c(x,y)$ some terms with $\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial c}{\partial y}$ would appear.

In the elementary case of $c=$constant one can separate 
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + c\frac{\partial }{\partial y}=0$$
and 
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} - c\frac{\partial }{\partial y}=0$$
The method of characteristics leads to the solutions, respectively :
$$u_1(x,y)=f(y+cx)$$
and 
$$u_2(x,y)=g(y-cx)$$
where $f$ and $g$ are independent arbitrary functions.

So, the general solution of $\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial^{2} x} - c^2\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial^{2} y} =0$ is :
$$u(x,y)=f(y+cx)+g(y-cx)$$

If the equation is $\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial^{2} x} + c\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial^{2} y} =0$, the general solution is :
$$u(x,y)=f(y+i\sqrt{c}\:x)+g(y-i\sqrt{c}\:x)$$

ADDITION after the discussion in the comments section :

Solving $\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + c_{0}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)u=0$ 
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}=1\:,\quad x(0)=x_0 \quad\text{leads to}\quad x=t+x_0 \\
\frac{dy}{dt}=c_0\:,\quad y(0)=y_0 \quad\text{leads to}\quad y=c_0t+y_0 \\
\frac{du}{dt}=0\:,\quad u(0)=u_0 \quad\text{leads to}\quad u=u_0 
\end{cases}$$
A first family of characteristic curves  comes from $x=t+x_0$ and $y=c_0t+y_0$ which are the parametric equation of $y=c_0(x-x_0)+y_0$
$$y-c_0x=c_1\quad\text{with}\quad c_1=y_0-c_0x_0.$$
A second family of characteristic curves comes from $\quad u=u_0=$constant$=c_2$

The general solution of the PDE $\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + c_{0}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)u=0$ expressed on the form of implicit equation is 
$$F(c_1,c_2)=F(y-c_0x\:,\: u)=0$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function of two variables.

Or, equivalently on explicit form :
$$u=g(y-c_0x)$$
where $g$ is an arbitrary function.

Comment: Yeah, the signal was wrong! So, my doubt is in the application of the method of characteristic. I was unable to apply it as described in the problem. If you could help me with one of the two equations would be great.

Comment: I cannot understand your question. From what equations are you taking about ?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}  + c\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - c\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$. Besides, should not I do $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - c\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)u(x,y) = v(x,y)$ before?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand exactly what your specific problem is. From what PDE those two equations are coming from? What is $c$, a function or a constant ?

Comment: $c$ is a constant. These two equations came when I "broke" the wave equation in two parts. So I'm trying to use the system Sy 1, applying the method of characteristics, to find the solution of the wave equation from these two PDEs. So I called the first part of $ v $ to find a solution to equation (2). Then, use the solution of equation (2) to solve equation (1).

Comment: I need to apply the method of characteristics only in equation (1), but I wanted to solve the two equations with this method. I'm having trouble applying the method the way it's described in the problem. It seems like a lot of conditions for a simple PDE and this is making me a bit confused.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not clear yet.

Comment: The wording of your question is confusing. They are two different equations noted $(1)$. One is in the original problem, the other is introduced later by you . So when you refer to equation $1$ it is doubtful. Also, the same symbol $c$ is used in different contexts, one where $c=c(x,y)$, the other where $c=$constant. I still am not sure about what is the original PDE that you want to solve. Please, don't answer to the present comment. Better re-edit your question.

Comment: Is better now? ${}$

Comment: You have not well corrected your equation which is still false : $$\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial^{2} x} - c_{0}\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial^{2} y} = \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + c_{0}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} - c_{0}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)u = 0.$$

Comment: I apologize. I forgot, but I corrected now

Comment: OK. Now, what PDE do you want to solve ? Is it $\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} - c_{0}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)u = 0$ ?

Comment: I think in solve the equation (2) first, using the Problem, but is there any more convenient order? Because I need to apply the Problem once and then I'm free to use whatever I want.

Comment: At this step of your calculus,  what PDE do you want to solve ? Is it $\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + c_{0}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)u =0$ ? Yes or No ?

Comment: Yes, it is! ${}$

Comment: See the addition to my first answer.

Comment: Awsome! Thank you very much! I got it!

Comment: @JJacquelin, Can you clarify to me some points?

Comment: @Greg. What points?

Comment: First: why $F(c_1,c_2) = 0$? who's $F$? I have no idea. Second: why $u = g(y-c_{0}x)$? Here, I tried to use the implicit function theorem, but I don't know what it would be like to calculate $F_u$. After, using the same ideia I will to got $u=f(y + c_{0}x)$. We know that the solution is $u(x,y) = f(y + c_{0}x) + g(y - c_{0}x)$... why the solution is the sum of the solutions to two one-dimensional equations?

Comment: I open this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2926608/understand-some-points-of-method-of-characteristic-and-the-solution-of-the-wave. I asked a lot of questions. Maybe it's not good to answer them here.

Comment: @Greg. $\:F\:$ is an arbitrary function until no boundary condition is specified. How could we say that in other words ? Of course, in expressing the general solution of the PDE on this implicit form, we apply a background of knowledge provided by a theory. To understand what is behind, we have to know about the theory, which is not a small task. I am afraid that is not possible to write here pages of academic books. Sorry, in a simple comment I cannot answer to such too wide questions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what your specific problem is, but for a general description of the method of characteristics for the one-dimensional wave equation $$u_t+c(u)u_x=0$$ (which includes the linear case with $c(u)=c_0$ constant), I can recommend Chapter 2 of Whitham's [Linear and Nonlinear Waves](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471359424).

Comment: Yeah! I thought the general case follows the same idea. Because I only tried this case, I just wrote it. It was my mistake, it was really confusing. I will correct. Thanks for the book!